# Fibration defined by homogeneous space, how to find an indused map on cohomology ring?(or maybe any fibration at all, I am missing something)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I would like to ask a question regarding this paper

https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1967-129-01/S0002-9947-1967-0216504-6/S0002-9947-1967-0216504-6.pdf

Mainly this example on page 88:
[image]

Could you please explain why $\rho^*$ is exactly that?

And how to understand this in general case? For example, if we view $\mathbb{C}P^n$ as a homogeneous space $\frac{U(n+1)}{U(1)\times U(n)}$ and consider fibration
$$
\mathbb{C}P^n \rightarrow B\left[U(1) \times U(n) \right] \rightarrow BU(n+1)
$$
then, if I'm not wrong, by the Künneth formula $H^*(B\left[U(1) \times U(n) \right], \mathbb{Z}) = 
H^*(BU(1) \times BU(n), \mathbb{Z}) = 
\mathbb{Z}[b_2, c_2, \dots, c_{2n}]$, and
as the induced morphism we have $\rho^* : \mathbb{Z}[c_2, c_4, \dots, c_{2n+2}] \rightarrow 
\mathbb{Z}[b_2, c_2, c_4, \dots, c_{2n}]$ .
What will it do in this case and why? It "feels" like it should preserve degree(but why again?) and send $c_2$ to $c_2$ and so on; if so, it must do something with $c_{2n+2}$ as well.

My advisor said that it's something simple, but I seem to lack theoretical knowledge or to overlook some theorem or a trick, maybe. Anyways, thank you a lot.

Comment: Do you know spectral sequences?

Comment: $1)$ $\rho^*$ acts the way it does because of the way the Stiefel-Whitney classes are defined (or if you prefer, becuase of their basic properties. ie. use stability: $w_k(E\oplus\epsilon^l)=w_k(E)$ where $\epsilon^l$ is the trivial $l$-plane bundle). Presumably you have to have made a sensible definition of these objects to have written down the cohomology rings beforehand.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, that's right. Not that I could say that I know them well, but trying to understand above question in order to calculate cohomology of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ via the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence.

Comment: @Tyrone Then in example of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ should I find aforementioned morphism as Stiefel-Whitney classes of cartesian product $EU(n)\times EU(1) \rightarrow BU(n)\times BU(1)$? And strangely enough, no, I haven't thought about this at all when I was writing cohomology rings, I just thought what tensor product of polynomial rings would look like. I'm still a bit new to this topic so there's a chance that I said complete nonsence at some point.

Comment: Edit: since there is U(n) action I should use Chern classes instead, I guess...

Comment: Let $j:T_n\subseteq U_n$ be the maximal torus consisting of the diagonal matrices. The induced map $Bj^*:H^*BU_n\rightarrow H^*BT_n$ is monic. Note that $T_n\cong \prod^n_{i=1}S^1$. We have $ H^*BT^n\cong \mathbb{Z}[t_1,\dots,t_n]$, where $|t_i|=2$, and $Bj^*c_i=\sigma_i(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ is the ith symmetric polynomial in the $t_i$ (this is the *splitting principle*). Now notice that $j$ factors as $T_n\cong T_{n-1}\times S^1\rightarrow U_{n-1}\times S^1\rightarrow U_n$. The second map is what you are interested in. You know the action on cohomology of the composite and of the first.